# Why can't I use the variance of the sample average in the Central Limit Theorem for the weak-stationary process?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Under mild conditions $\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^2/n}}$ approaches the standard normal (where $\sigma^2$ is the process variance, not the marginal variance $\sigma^2_x$).

Why is the denominator not the standard error for the sample mean of dependent data, specifically
$\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n}\times [1 + 2*\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(1-i/n)*\rho_i]}$
?

A high-level answer would be nice as I don't have a good background in mathematics.

I didn't put this in CrossValidated because it deals with probability and stochastic processes.

Comment: I have exactly the same question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central limit theorem applies only to strongly stationary processes, where all of the $\rho_i$'s are equal to the variance. In this situation, the one formula reduces to the other.